# What is the LESS environment variable to man and how is it set up?

Tags: environment-variables, man, less

What is the `LESS` environment variable used for in `man`? I found that it could make the output of `man` jump to a match to the pattern stored in `LESS`. What about when there are several matches?

How is the pattern set up in `LESS`?  What kind of regex is used?
For example,in `LESS=+/'^ *shopt \[' man bash`, what does `+/` mean?

Does `LESS` affect other commands than `man`?
Is it possible to achieve the same in the std output of another command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LESS` has no special meaning to `man`, but `less` pager, which `man` uses by default on most systems.

On my Debian, if no pager was specified, `man` will use `pager -s` by default.

```
$ readlink -f "$(command -v pager)"
/bin/less
```

`LESS` specifies which options will be passed to `less`. The `+cmd` tell `less` to execute `cmd` upon open. Here `+/'^ *shopt \['` tells `less` to search for line match regex `^ *shopt \[`, which you can do manually by running `man bash`, then pressing `/` and typing the regex.

If you change the pager, `LESS` has no effect:

```
LESS=+/'^ *shopt \[' man -P more bash
```

Comment: cuong, also to note that `pager` is governed by the Debian alternatives system in Debian and derivatives..